# Forge 1.20.4 MDK fails when building gradle

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

When i run ./gradlew genEclipseRuns it fails to build and i get the error

```
PS C:\Users\camer\Desktop\MinecraftCoding\MinecraftJava> ./gradlew genEclipseRuns
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\camer\Desktop\MinecraftCoding\MinecraftJava\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', version: '[6.0.16,6.2)'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:net.minecraftforge.gradle.gradle.plugin:[6.0.16,6.2)')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    MinecraftForge(https://maven.minecraftforge.net/)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

how do i fix this i have the latest java installed also and am on windows

I tried to build the mdk gradle and instead of succeeding it failed with an exception

Answer (score 0):

fixed it i accidentally had the wrong java version installed and i didnt have jdk 8 set to java home i fixed it all now tho